# Define an invisible caption

Tags: xetex, memoir

Short Question: How can I make a caption, which is not shown in document?

Long version: I am using xelatex with memoir and trying to make a figure going over 2 pages. Basically, something like:

```
\begin{figure}

\subbottom[some name]{\includegraphics{pic.png}\label{somelabel}}
\caption{somecaption}

\end{figure}

\begin{figure}

\contsubbottom[some name2]{\includegraphics{pic2.png}\label{somelabel2}}
\сontcaption{somecaption}
\subconcluded
\end{figure}
```

I don't want the first caption to appear anywhere or to be shown in my figure, but I can't let it out, because otherwise the indexation and references are messed up - figures are counted with separate numbers. So, I need to redefine the first caption "on place" to make it invisible. Is there some way to do so?

Comment: You can use `subcaption` package and its `\phantomcaption` command.

Comment: Thanks, works! The only issue now is that images are numbered in figure and references as "1.1.1a" instead of "1.1.1(a)", but this is a minor issue. I have to look into documentation of the subcaption package, I guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typeset the mock caption in a box that's discarded:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newsubfloat{figure}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Test}

\ref{X}

\begin{figure}[htp]
\centering
\subbottom[some name]{\includegraphics[width=5cm]{example-image-a}\label{somelabel}}
\setbox0=\vbox{\caption{somecaption}}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[htp]
\centering
\contsubbottom[some name2]{\includegraphics[width=5cm]{example-image-b}\label{somelabel2}}
\contcaption{somecaption}\label{X}
\subconcluded
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Note that the reference number is correct (but not the name reference).

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I've done it already with \phantomcaption, but your approach works too!