# Using floats to create a list of definitions, but without seeing captions in the document?

Tags: floats, captions, indexing

I'm writing a document with a lot of examples, definitions, diagrams etc (category theory, you may have guessed), and I want to provide indexes listing them all - I have produced something like the following:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{stix}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[document]{ragged2e}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{float}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows,bending,calc,patterns}

\newcommand\irregularcircle[2]{% radius, irregularity
    \pgfextra {\pgfmathsetmacro\len{(#1)+rand*(#2)}}
    +(0:\len pt)
    \foreach \a in {10,20,...,350}{
        \pgfextra {\pgfmathsetmacro\len{(#1)+rand*(#2)}}
        -- +(\a:\len pt)
    } -- cycle
}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{mydef}{Definition}[section]
\newtheorem{ex}{Example}[section]
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]

\floatstyle{plain}
\newfloat{defn}{thp}{def}[section]
\floatname{defn}{Definition}
\newfloat{exmp}{thp}{ex}[section]
\floatname{exmp}{Example}
\newfloat{diag}{htbp}{dia}[section]
\floatname{diag}{Diagram}
\newfloat{tab}{thp}{tab}[section]
\floatname{tab}{Table}
\newfloat{thrm}{thp}{thm}[section]
\floatname{thrm}{Theorem}

\makeatletter
\everymath{\if@display\else\thickmuskip=2mu plus 2mu\fi}
\renewcommand*{\listof}[2]{%
    \@ifundefined{ext@#1}{\float@error{#1}}{%
        \@namedef{l@#1}{\@dottedtocline{1}{1.5em}{3em}}% <-------  replaced 2.3em with 3em here
        \float@listhead{#2}%
        \begingroup\setlength{\parskip}{\z@}%
            \@starttoc{\@nameuse{ext@#1}}%
        \endgroup}}
\makeatother

\title{Notes to Topoi - the categorial analysis of logic\\by Robert Goldblatt}
\author{Jan Andersen}

\begin{document}
    \listof{defn}{Definitions}
    \chapter{Mathematics = Set Theory?}
    \section{Set Theory}
    \begin{defn}[H]
        \begin{mydef}
%           \setbox0=\vbox{\caption{Principle of Comprehension}}
            \caption{Principle of Comprehension}
            \label{def:PrincipleofComprehension}
            \textbf{Principle of Comprehension}\\
            If $\phi(x)$ is a property or condition pertaining to objects $x$, then there exists a set whose elements are precisely the objects that have the property $\phi(x)$
        \end{mydef}
    \end{defn}
\end{document}
```

This gives me the list(s), but I also get captions where I don't want them:

[image]

How can I suppress the display of the captions? I tried out the suggestions in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/227616/define-an-invisible-caption), but it doesn't work for me - the entry disappears from my index, but the caption stays.

Comment: It seems completely wrong to be using floats here. definitions, theorems etc are part of the main document flow they are not floating inserts. Declaring them as floats and then using the "quick fix"  `[H]` attribute on every one to make it a non-float seems very strange markup

Comment: @DavidCarlisle You may well be right - I haven't learned this in a systematic way, so I'm just doing my best. Is there a canonical way to produce a these lists? I'll be very happy to learn.

Comment: searching this site for "list of theorems" shows several hits eg https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/249963/remove-repeated-theorem-in-the-list-of-theorems

Comment: Probably you can define your mydef and related theorem-like environments via thmtools and use its built in listofthrorems command.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle - as always, the answer is clear, once you ask the right question. Thanks.

Comment: @leandriis Thanks to you too - I'll see what thmtools can do

Comment: @j4nd3r53n if you have something working, feel free to post a self-answer to get this off the list of unanswered questions:-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For completeness, and with thanks to David Carlisle's and leandriis' comments, this is what does the job for me:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}% just for the example
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd\thmt@mklistcmd
  {\thmt@thmname}
  {\check@optarg{\thmt@thmname}}
  {}{}
\patchcmd\thmt@mklistcmd
  {\thmt@thmname\ifx}
  {\check@optarg{\thmt@thmname}\ifx}
  {}{}
\protected\def\check@optarg#1{%
  \@ifnextchar\thmtformatoptarg\@secondoftwo{#1}%
}
\makeatother

\declaretheoremstyle[
  spaceabove=6pt, spacebelow=6pt,
  headfont=\normalfont\bfseries,
  postheadspace=1em,
  notefont=\bfseries,
  notebraces={(}{)},
  bodyfont=\itshape,
  shaded={bgcolor=yellow!20}
]{thmstyle}

\declaretheorem[style=thmstyle,name=Theorem]{theorem}
\declaretheorem[style=thmstyle,name=Example]{example}

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}[Somebody]
...
\end{theorem}

\begin{theorem}
...
\end{theorem}

\begin{example}[First example]
    ...
\end{example}

\begin{example}[Next example]
    ...
\end{example}

\begin{example}[Final example]
    ...
\end{example}

\renewcommand{\listtheoremname}{List of Theorems}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\listtheoremname}
\listoftheorems[ignoreall,show=theorem]
\renewcommand{\listtheoremname}{List of Examples}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\listtheoremname}
\listoftheorems[ignoreall,show=example]

\end{document}
```

Comment: If this solved your problem, you should mark the answer as such.